# PhantomJS executable in openshift server with python

Tags: python, phantomjs, openshift

Manually downloaded PhantomJS executable in openshift app,

I called phantomjs.

```
driver=webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='/var/lib/openshift/<some_string>/phantomjs/usr/phantomjs',port=8080,service_args= ['--ignore-ssl-errors=true', '--ssl-protocol=any','--webdriver-loglevel=SEVERE'],service_log_path='/var/lib/openshift/<some_string>/app-root/repo/wsgi/myproject/ghostdriver.log')
```

But It throws error, that executable unexpectedly exited.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service/var/lib/openshift/<some_string>/phantomjs/usr/phantomjs unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 1.
```

Could someone help to get over this?

Thanks in advance.